# NodeJS and MongoDB losing connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `7 NodeJS` with `Mongoose` webservices running in a small instance on `Amazon AWS` and a `MongoDB` in another small instance.

Everything works with low usage (both cpu, memory and network traffic), without any high peaks.

But some times it seems that these `NodeJS` services loses connection with `MongoDB`. All methods from services that do not use `Mongoose` keep working normally. The ones that uses Mongoose keep in an endless call without any response. I need to restart the services to they respond again.

It happens randomly and there is no pattern I could figure out.

Another strange thing is that in average all services stop together. It`s rare to happen with just one, but happens.

I could try separating all services into a single server each, but it would be very expensive. But first I would like to find out what is happening and fix it up.

Can someone help me?

Comment: That very much sounds like your code has a bug where – in certain conditions – it doesn't send back a response to the browser. Which looks exactly like you describe: *"an endless call without any response"*. @yttrium is correct about Mongoose automatically reconnecting, so it might not at all be related to Mongoose.

Comment: That`s one of the things I`m thinking about. The problem is, node doesn`t throw any kind of error message, which makes any analysis harder.

Comment: It's not an error situation when you don't send a response back, your browser will just wait and (eventually) time out. Perhaps you can post one of your routes for which the problems occur?

Comment: +1 please write how to solve it if you know it

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding option '?auto_reconnect=true' to the connection string may be solve your problem.

But, according to the documentation Mongoose enables auto_reconnect by default.

There is may be more chance to understand what happens, if you post logs of your node.js and mongodb servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer yttrium! The problem is the connection still exists, it just don`t get closed and there is no error logs or messages. It just stops responding...

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version as there have been a lot of bugfixes in the driver